# Why I cannot get the value of associated data through ${book.type.sortName} in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, web, mybatis

I'm a beginner in Java web.I am using spring4 mvc and mybatis for the book manage system.

There are two tables **t_book** and **t_type** in database bms in mysql.

This is the **Book** entity:

```
public class Book {

    private Long bookNum;

    private String bookName;

    private String writer;

    private String callNumber;

    private BigDecimal price;

    private String pubCompany;

    private Date pubDate;

    private Long totalNum;

    private Long currentNum;

    private String brief;

    private Type type; // the associated class

    // getter and setter

}
```

This is the **Type** entity:

```
public class Type {

    private Long sortId;

    private String sortName;

    // getter and setter
}
```

But in the bookDetail.jsp,the page **can** show the value of ${book.bookName},${book.writer},${book.pubDate} and so on,but **cannot** show the value of **${book.type.sortName}**.

This is a part of bookDetail.jsp:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book ID</th>
                        <td>${book.bookNum}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book name</th>
                        <td>${book.bookName}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book writer</th>
                        <td>${book.writer}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>callNumber</th>
                        <td>${book.callNumber}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>sort</th>
                        <td>${book.type.sortName}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>publish Date</th>
                        <td><fmt:formatDate value="${book.pubDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Why I can't get the value of associated data through ${book.type.sortName} in .jsp? How can I get it?

Please help! 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are retrieving the model as a Lazy, so you have only the first part you won't have the value of the association just the reference, you can check that if you put just the ${book.type} will give you the reference of Type only.

Comment: No,I also cannot get the value of ${book.type} .

Answer (score 0):

In your sql mapping xml, change the attribute lazyLoadingEnabled as:

```
lazyLoadingEnabled="false"
```